# jQuery get index of certain child elements and ignore others

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the index of a child element `ol`, but there is also some `h2`'s in there which I don't need and are therefore polluting my results when using the jQuery `index()` function.

So I need the index of the `ol`, as if there weren't any `h2`'s at all. So that if you click on the 3rd `ol` the index will be `2` and not `4`.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <ol><li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li></ol>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <ol><li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li></ol>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <ol><li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li></ol>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <ol><li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li></ol>
</div>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$('ol li').click(function () {
    // get current index position of the ol
    var itemIndex   = $(this).parent('ol').index();

    alert(itemIndex);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I well understood, try this code

```
var ol = $('ol');
ol.find('li').click(function () {
    var parentOl  = $(this).parent('ol');
    // get current index position of the ol
    var itemIndex = ol.index(parentOl);
    alert(itemIndex);
});
```

example jsbin : http://jsbin.com/enugex/1/edit

Comment: I've got it working, but could you please explain how it works?

Answer (score 2):

modify your code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dzk8B/1/)

```
$('ol li').click(function (item,index) {
    // get current index position of the ol
      var itemIndex   = $(this).parents('div').children('ol').index($(this).parent('ol'));

    alert(itemIndex);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(this).parent('ol').parent().children('ol').indexOf($(this).parent('ol'));
```